# XML Serialization issue in ActiveRecord serializable attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-serialization

I have a serialized field called options(of type Hash) in my User model. The options field behaves like a Hash most of the time. When I convert the user object to XML, the 'options' field is serialized as a YAML type instead of Hash.

I am sending the result to a Flash client via REST. This behaviour is causing problems at the client side. Is there a way to address this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :options, Hash
end

u = User.first
u.options[:theme] =  "Foo"
u.save

p u.options # prints the Hash

u.to_xml    # options is serialized as a yaml type: 
            # <options type=\"yaml\">--- \n:theme: Foo\n</options>
```

## EDIT:

I am working around this issue by passing a block to to_xml.(similar to the solution suggested by molf)

```
u.to_xml(:except => [:options])  do |xml|
  u.options.to_xml(:builder => xml, :skip_instruct => true, :root => 'options')
end
```

I wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Serialisation is done with YAML in the database. What they don't tell you is that it is also passed as YAML to the XML serializer. The last argument to `serialize` indicates that the objects you **assign** to `options` should be of type `Hash`.

One solution to your problem is to override `to_xml` with your own implementation. It's relatively easy to borrow the original xml builder object and pass it to `to_xml` of your `options` hash. Something like this should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :options, Hash

  def to_xml(*args)
    super do |xml|
      # Hash#to_xml is unaware that the builder is in the middle of building
      # XML output, so we tell it to skip the <?xml...?> instruction. We also
      # tell it to use <options> as its root element name rather than <hash>.
      options.to_xml(:builder => xml, :skip_instruct => true, :root => "options")
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I am using a similar approach now. Refer to my EDIT to the original question. Since I wasn't clear about that I will vote +1 for your answer. In your solution you do need to add :except to the args to ignore 'options'. Otherwise you end up with two 'options' field in the serialized XML string.